# I cannot seem to get the grey background out from this layout(as attached)

Tags: html, css

I have tried sourcing in html & css for the main background but it is the same as the previous copies. Tried div tag, didnt work too

[Expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CNwR.png)

In the end im getting [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49oyL.png)

Comment: provide your code so we can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try giving background color to body tag

Using CSS Style

```
body {background-color: grey;}
```

Using CSS Inline

```
<html>
    <body style="background-color:grey;">
    </body>
</html>
```